# Buttons setText from shuffled list item positions display wrong results

Tags: android, list, shuffle

I have a String array with numbers "25", "50", "75", "100"
and I'm using the method below to shuffle the positions of list' s items.

```
public List<String> listNums() {

    List<String> numList = Arrays.asList(Nums);

    Collections.shuffle(numList);
    return numList;
```

I have also this method to assign the list items to 4 buttons:

```
protected void SetTxtNums(){
    NumGenerator numGen = new NumGenerator();

    bNum2.setText(numGen.listNums().get(0).toString());
    bNum3.setText(numGen.listNums().get(1).toString());
    bNum4.setText(numGen.listNums().get(2).toString());
    bNum5.setText(numGen.listNums().get(3).toString());
}
```

And I'm trying by click on another button to change the text to above buttons, which doesn't work.
The onClick code is this:

```
case R.id.bNumGen:
        SetTxtNums();           
        break;
```

The problem is that generates dublicate values. I want every button to have a different number, just the positions to change.

If I include a toast for testing like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), numGen.listBigNums().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

then on toast I get correct results, buttons are completely different and with same values for two or even three of them.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you did shuffle on different lists rather the required one.And second your logic is wrong.Try something like this.

```
List<String> numList = Arrays.asList(Nums);
public List<String> listNums() {
return numlist;
}

public void shuffleList() {
    Collections.shuffle(intList);
    return numList;
}
```

now do like this :

```
protected void SetTxtNums(){
    NumGenerator numGen = new NumGenerator();
    numGen.shuffleList();

    bNum2.setText(numGen.listNums().get(0).toString());
    bNum3.setText(numGen.listNums().get(1).toString());
    bNum4.setText(numGen.listNums().get(2).toString());
    bNum5.setText(numGen.listNums().get(3).toString());
}
```

Comment: There aren't different lists, just a typo(intlist). I've corrected the code

Comment: Yes, it works thanks. But can you explain what was my logic mistake(if isn't much truble)?

Comment: @dancer_69 Sure.You are shuffling the list every time u r calling that listNums() function.So there may be possibility most of the time when the same number will come to the same place.got it ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

```
numGen.listNums()
```

returns a newly randomized list each time.